# Copy argument does not work with Range object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a table and paste it somewhere else (the target cell selected by the user) on the sheet:

[image]

But I get an error on the `table.copy` part:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
   Sub PasteMacro()
     Dim target As Variant
     Dim i As Long
     Dim table As Range
     Dim weight As Double
     Dim thickness As Double
     Dim Stiff As Double

     Set shA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("User sheet comp data")

     ' searh for the first non 0 ligne in the table

     i = 19
     Do Until Range("M" & i) <> 0
     i = i - 1
     Loop

     MsgBox Cells(i, 13).Address

     'the table to copy
     Set table = shA.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(i, 15))

     weight = shA.Range("O20")
     thickness = shA.Range("M20")
     Stiff = shA.Range("M21")


     On Error Resume Next
    ' ask the user to select the cell to paste table
    Set target = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a destination Cell where you want to 
    paste", Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not answ Is Nothing Then
    'copy the table and paste it
    table.Copy , shA.target
    End If

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.Copy , shA.target
```

should be
:

```
table.Copy target
```

since:

- the `Destination` parameter is the first one of the `Copy()` method, while commas are needed to delimit subsequent (if any) parameters
- `target` is a `Range` object, hence it's already fully qualifed up to its parent sheet and workbook object

Furthermore, I guess

```
If Not answ Is Nothing Then
```

should be
:

```
If Not Target Is Nothing Then
```

so here's the revised code

```
Sub PasteMacro()

    Dim target As Range
    Dim table As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim weight As Double
    Dim thickness As Double
    Dim Stiff As Double

    Dim shA As Worksheet

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("User sheet comp data")

        ' search for the first non 0 ligne in the table
        i = 19
        Do Until .Range("M" & i) <> 0
            i = i - 1
        Loop

        MsgBox .Cells(i, 13).Address

        'the table to copy
        Set table = .Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(i, 15))

        weight = .Range("O20").Value2
        thickness = .Range("M20").Value2
        Stiff = .Range("M21").Value2


        On Error Resume Next
        Set target = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a destination Cell where you want to Paste ", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not target Is Nothing Then table.Copy target  'copy the table and paste it

    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see all range objects (Range, Cells) are referencing `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("User sheet comp data")
("MilestoneDueDate")` through that dot (.) in front of them

this way you are sue you'r not loosing control over what range is being considered in what sheet